# Java Subclass Doesn't Inherit its Parent's Variable

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been working with my project and I having a problem inheriting parent class' variable.
Here's my code:

```
class function3 {

    double getTh;
    double getTt;
    double getOt;
    
    public void display(String name, String id, double getTh, double getTt, double getOt) {

        this.getTh = getTh;
        this.getTt = getTt;
        this.getOt = getOt;
        
        System.out.println("SALARY INFORMATION");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("Employee Id       : " + name);
        System.out.println("Employee Name     : " + id);
        System.out.println("Number of hours   : " + getTh);
        System.out.println("Employee Tardiness: " + getTt);
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        function4 displayTotal = new function4();
        displayTotal.calcSalary(getOt);
        displayTotal.displaySalary();
    }
    
    
}
```

```
class function4 extends function3 {

    double overtimePay;
    double weeklyIncome;
    
    public void calcSalary(double getOvertime) {

        overtimePay = getOvertime * 75.25;
        weeklyIncome = getTh * 200.50;
        
        System.out.println(weeklyIncome);
        
    }

    public void displaySalary() {

        System.out.println("WEEEKLY SALARY");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("Overtime Pay : " + overtimePay);
        System.out.println("Weekly Income: " + weeklyIncome);
        System.out.println("Gross Income : ");

    }
}
```

Now my problem is, I can't access the getTh variable from function3 even if it's already extended. What should I do?

Comment: I tried using get method but it's not even working.

Comment: Explain _I can't access the getTh variable_. Why not? Do you get a compilation error? Which one?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you expect `getTh` inside `calcSalary` to have the same value it has inside `display` from the parent class?

Comment: Yah, I can access I can't get its value, it doesn't show any error tho

Comment: What exactly is the error? Or what code you execute with these 2 classes?

Comment: @helloWorld that's not how inheritance works. You can't access the *value* the variable has in another instance, even if that other instance is of the parent class.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, Yah indeed!

Comment: Use in Function3 `protected double getTh;` so `getTh` is visible in `Function4`..

Comment: @user16320675 yeah I really need to have a function 4, my program requires to have an inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Subclasses cannot know, at runtime, about other instances of its parent class through inheritance alone

Subclasses have their own variables that get inherited, but this is only the attributes themselves, not any defined runtime values.

If you want access to another instance, you need composition, not inheritance

```
class function4 extends function3 {  // maybe not needed to extend anymore 
    public function4(function3 f) {
        this.f3 = f;
   } 
    function3 f3;
```

Then access `this.f3.getTh`

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you declare the variables `public`? By default in Java, variables are defined as package-private which means they are only visible to other classes in the same package, depending on how you have your project setup the 2 classes (function3 and function4) may be in different packages.

Also, as you progress through school (or learn on your own) you will discover that allowing a class to directly manipulate the variables in another can cause issues. S.O.L.I.D. is one of the current methodologies for designing useable and maintainable code. the O in solid means (among other things) that the `instance variables` of a class should not be able to be accessed by functions outside of the class. Instead you should design `accessors` and `mutators` (`getters` and `setters`), here is an example:

```
public class function 3 {

  private double Th;
  private double Tt;
  private double Ot;

  public double getTh() { return Th; }
  public void setTh(double newTh) { Th = newTh; }

  public double getTt() { return Tt; }
  public void setTt(double newTt) { Tt = newTt; }

  public double getOt() { return Ot; }
  public void setOt(double newOt) { Th = newOt; }

}
```

Then if you want to get the value of Th you can call `<instanceOfFunction3>.getTh()`